# Adding spinner after someone clicks submit HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know this is a hot mess, but I just need to add a spinner after someone clicks ok, and it errors our or completes.  I have no idea how to do front end, I just figured out azure functions like yesterday.  I can't believe this thing even works...

I am not sure exactly how to add the spinner or how to make it go away once the script is over.

I looked at a bunch of examples, but I'm stumped.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>GDAP Request </title>
    <style>
      form {
        max-width: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      input[type="text"],
      textarea {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-top: 6px;
        margin-bottom: 16px;
        resize: vertical;
      }
      input[type="submit"] {
        background-color: #4caf50;
        color: white;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      input[type="submit"]:hover {
        background-color: #45a049;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">GDAP Request</h2>

    <form id="contactForm">
      <label for="TenantID">Enter Tenant ID Here</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="TenantID"
        name="TenantID"
        placeholder="TenantID..."
        required
      />

      <label for="ClientContact">Email Address for Global Admin</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="ClientContact"
        name="ClientContact"
        placeholder="Client email..."
        required
      />

      <label for="gdapconfig">Select Permisions given to REMOVED</label>
        <select name="gdapconfig" id="gdapconfig"> 
            <option value="0">Support Only</option> 
            <option value="1">Cloudmore Basic</option> 
            <option value="2">Assisted GDAP</option> 
            <option value="3">Global Admin + Assist</option> 
        </select>


      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    <script>
      document
        .getElementById("contactForm")
        .addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          const formData = new FormData(this);
          const object = {};
          formData.forEach((value, key) => {
            object[key] = value;
          });
          const jsonData = JSON.stringify(object);

          let test = fetch(
            "https://fa-cus-afa-gdap-02.azurewebsites.net/api/gdapCreateRow?code=REMOVED-LdRyJ9Ac2LAzFujwNOSQ==",
            {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
              },
              body: jsonData,
            }
          )
            .then((response) => {
              if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("Network response was not ok");

              }
              return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
              alert("Client Add Complete.");
              var requestOptions = {
                  method: "POST",
                  redirect: "follow",
                };

                fetch(
                  "https://5f6fc7f3-d8a5-4d06-ad4a-67460f3fa3eb.webhook.cus.azure-automation.net/webhooks?token=REMOVED%2b%2bnFKr2GWrtHU1E4%3d",
                  requestOptions
                )
                  .then((response) => response.text())
                  .then((result) => console.log(result))
                  .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error(
                "There was an error sending the message:",
                jsonData
              );
              alert(
                "Client Add Complete.",
                test
              );
              var requestOptions = {
                  method: "POST",
                  redirect: "follow",
                };

                fetch(
                  "https://5f6fc7f3-d8a5-4d06-ad4a-67460f3fa3eb.webhook.cus.azure-automation.net/webhooks?token=REMOVED%2b%2bnFKr2GWrtHU1E4%3d",
                  requestOptions
                )
                  .then((response) => response.text())
                  .then((result) => console.log(result))
                  .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
            });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-yyokfc?file=index.html